# CardView does not show and app crashes

Tags: java, android, mobile, parse-platform

I am trying to put strings in parse and put them later in a CardView item.
It is not working....

Error: You must create this type of ParseObject using ParseObject.create() or the proper subclass.

ListViewAdapter:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Post> {
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    ArrayList<Post> data = new ArrayList<Post>();

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
                           ArrayList<Post> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        RecordHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new RecordHolder();
            holder.airport_name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_airport);
            holder.imageItem = (ParseImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
            holder.date = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_date);
            holder.time = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_time);
            holder.username = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_username);

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else { // recycle view if any
            holder = (RecordHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        Post item = data.get(position);
        holder.airport_name.setText(item.getAirportParse());
        holder.date.setText(item.getDateParse());
        holder.time.setText(item.getTimeParse());
        holder.username.setText(item.getUsername());

        if (item.getImageFile() != null) {
            holder.imageItem.setParseFile(item.getImageFile());
        } else {
            holder.imageItem.setImageResource(R.drawable.rsz_add_post2);
            holder.imageItem.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        }

        return row;

    }

    static class RecordHolder {
        TextView airport_name;
        TextView date;
        TextView time;
        TextView username;
        ParseImageView imageItem;
    }
}
```

Post:

```
@ParseClassName("Post")
public class Post extends ParseObject implements Serializable {

    public Post(){

    }

    public String getId(){
        return getString("objectId");
    }

    public void setId(String id){
        put("objectId", id);
    }

    //////////

    public String getUsername(){
        return getString("username");
    }




    public String getAirportParse(){
        return getString("airport");
    }

    public void setAirportParse(String airport){
        put("airport", airport);
    }

    //////////


    public String getDateParse(){
        return getString("date");
    }

    public void setDateParse(String date){
        put("date", date);
    }


    //////////


    public String getTimeParse(){
        return getString("time");
    }

    public void setTimeParse(String time){
        put("time", time);
    }


    //////////


    public String getPersonsParse(){
        return getString("persons");
    }

    public void setPersonsParse(String persons){
        put("persons", persons);
    }


    //////////


    public String getAddressParse(){
        return getString("address");
    }

    public void setAddressParse(String address){
        put("address", address);
    }

    public String getFlightnrParse(){
        return getString("flightnr");
    }

    public void setFlightnrParse(String flightnr){
        put("flightnr", flightnr);
    }


    public ParseFile getImageFile(){
        return getParseFile("image");
    }

    public void setImageFile(ParseFile file) {
        if (file != null) {
            put("image", file);
        }
    }


    public List<String> getPosts(){
        return getList("Post");
    }
    public void setIngredients(List<String> postsLists){
        if (postsLists != null)
            put("Post", postsLists);
    }
}
```

FinishPostFragment:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.add_post_finish:
            // User chose the "Favorite" action, mark the current item
            // as a favorite...
            final FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
            final Fragment fragment = new DemandFragment();

            // put strings to listview in DemandFragment
            ParseObject post = new ParseObject("Post");

            post.put("airport", airport_finish.getText().toString());
            post.put("date", date_finish.getText().toString());
            post.put("time", time_finish.getText().toString());
            post.put("persons", persons_finish.getText().toString());
            post.put("address", address_finish.getText().toString());
            post.put("flightnr", flightnr_finish.getText().toString());

            post.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, fragment).commit();
                }
            });

            return true;
```

DemandFragment:

```
public class DemandFragment extends Fragment {

    ListView lv;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Post> mijncode;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_demand, container, false);

        if(rootView != null){
            lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listDemand);

            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item_cardview, mijncode);

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    // clicked on item show post
                    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
                    Fragment fragment = new ViewPostFragment();
                    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, fragment).commit();
                }
            });
        }

        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Post");

        mijncode = new ArrayList<Post>();

        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> postList, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (ParseObject object : postList) {
                        Post newPost = new Post();

                        newPost.setAirportParse((String) object.get("airport"));
                        newPost.setDateParse((String) object.get("date"));
                        newPost.setTimeParse((String) object.get("time"));
                        newPost.setPersonsParse((String) object.get("persons"));
                        newPost.setAddressParse((String) object.get("address"));
                        newPost.setFlightnrParse((String) object.get("address"));

                        mijncode.add(newPost);
                    }

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error you wrote, you are supposed to initialize the `ParseObject` by calling `ParseObject.create()`, but you never call that method. In all cases (post in FinishPostFragment and newPost in DemandFragment), you call the constructor and never `ParseObject.create()`... If you could provide the line where this error is, it would be easier to say which one causes it.

EDIT: I'm not really familiar with Parse and I never had to make subclasses, [Parse docs](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#subclasses-defining) explains quite well what is needed to make a subclass, and it seems it has nothing to do with the super constructor, my mistake.

Comment: at rang.afterflight.Post.<init>(Post.java:16)

which gives:

    public Post(){

    }

Comment: @Rang92 So, the error is thrown when you call the constructor to `Post`... As it extends `ParseObject`, it could be that you need to either call the super constructor or call `ParseObject.create()`  inside `Post()`. You could try with calling the super constructor first.

Comment: @Rang92 Can't you add `super();` or `super("post");` inside your `Post()`, like `public Post(){ super("post"); }`? I saw that the subclass must have a default constructor with no parameters but it still can do something, it doesn't need to be completely empty.

Comment: With Post newPost = new Post(super("posts"));
In Object cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)

Comment: With Post newPost = new Post(super());

Call to 'super()' must be first statement in constructor body

Comment: @Rang92 Not as a parameter! It should be in the constructor definition, in your Post class, not in your DemandFragment. Like this: [Java inheritance](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_inheritance.html) However, I found while reading Parse docs, you need to register the subclass with `ParseObject.registerSubclass(Post.class)` and after `Parse.initialize`. Did you do this?

Comment: @Rang92 Great! What did you do? Also don't forget to accept the answer if you think this really solved your problem ;)

Comment: I forgot to do this in onCreat instead of onCreateView:

adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item_cardview, mijncode);
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);